# Primary key getting issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I know the primary index of a table record and want to get next row after that index .for example if primary index of a record is 3 and next row primary index is 6 then how can i get the next row if i know the primary index 3.i am using Sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: Why you tag your question with mysql if you use sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [TABLE] T
WHERE T.ID > @KnownID
ORDER BY ID
```

Where @KnownID is the primary key that you know about.